# Forward reference extends over definition of variable in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming

I have a list. For all the numbers in odd position I want to make it 0. And for all the numbers in even position, I want to keep it as it is.I'm trying to do it via map in the following way.

Here's my code

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
var l1 = List (1,2,3,4,5,6)

println(l1.map(f(_)))
var c = 0
def f(n:Int):Int =
{

  if (c%2 == 0)
    {c +=1
    return n}
  else
    {c += 1
    return 0}
```

I want the variable to keep track of the position. But as it seems,I can't forward reference 'c'.

I get the following error

> scala forward reference extends over definition of variable c

I can't also declare 'c' inside the function, because it will never increment that way.

What should be the idea way to achieve what I am trying, with the help of map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a list. For all the numbers in odd position I want to make it
>   0. And for all the numbers in even position, I want to keep it as it is.

Here's an elegant solution of this problem:

```
l1.zipWithIndex map { case (v, i) => if (i % 2 == 0) v else 0 }
```

---

As for the reason, why your code fails: you're trying to access variable `c` before its declaration in code. Here:

```
println(l1.map(f(_)))
var c = 0
```

Your function `f` is trying to access variable `c`, which is not declared yet. Reorder these two lines and it will work. But I'd recommend to stick with my initial approach.